# OIDC Redirect URI Error in Dockerized Django

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, openid-connect

I'm running two applications using docker-compose. Each application has a bunch of containers. The intention is for `App A` (django app) to host the OIDC provider, while `App B` (some other app) will authenticate users by calling the `App A` API.

I'm using the django-oidc-provider library (https://django-oidc-provider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

I've already configured the OIDC integration on both sides. However, every time `App B` redirects to `App A`, I hit the following error:

```
Redirect URI Error
The request fails due to a missing, invalid, or mismatching redirection URI (redirect_uri).
```

Even though the redirect_uri matches exactly on both sides.

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: datahub-gms_default

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: dqt
    container_name: dqt
    hostname: dqt
    platform: linux/x86_64
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app:z
    environment:
      - DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE=true
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    hostname: postgres
    volumes:
      - dqt_local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
      - dqt_local_postgres_data_backups:/backups:z
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres

  broker:
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      - KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
      - KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS=0
      - KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx256m
    hostname: broker
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.0
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
      - 9092:9092
  
  datahub-actions:
    depends_on:
      - datahub-gms
    environment:
      - GMS_HOST=datahub-gms
      - GMS_PORT=8080
      - KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER=broker:29092
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://schema-registry:8081
      - METADATA_AUDIT_EVENT_NAME=MetadataAuditEvent_v4
      - METADATA_CHANGE_LOG_VERSIONED_TOPIC_NAME=MetadataChangeLog_Versioned_v1
      - DATAHUB_SYSTEM_CLIENT_ID=__datahub_system
      - DATAHUB_SYSTEM_CLIENT_SECRET=JohnSnowKnowsNothing
      - KAFKA_PROPERTIES_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=PLAINTEXT
    hostname: actions
    image: public.ecr.aws/datahub/acryl-datahub-actions:${ACTIONS_VERSION:-head}
  
  datahub-frontend-react:
    container_name: datahub-frontend-react
    depends_on:
      - datahub-gms
    environment:
      - DATAHUB_GMS_HOST=datahub-gms
      - DATAHUB_GMS_PORT=8080
      - DATAHUB_SECRET=YouKnowNothing
      - DATAHUB_APP_VERSION=1.0
      - DATAHUB_PLAY_MEM_BUFFER_SIZE=10MB
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m -Dhttp.port=9002 -Dconfig.file=datahub-frontend/conf/application.conf
        -Djava.security.auth.login.config=datahub-frontend/conf/jaas.conf -Dlogback.configurationFile=datahub-frontend/conf/logback.xml
        -Dlogback.debug=false -Dpidfile.path=/dev/null
      - KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER=broker:29092
      - DATAHUB_TRACKING_TOPIC=DataHubUsageEvent_v1
      - ELASTIC_CLIENT_HOST=elasticsearch
      - ELASTIC_CLIENT_PORT=9200
      - AUTH_OIDC_ENABLED=true
      - AUTH_OIDC_CLIENT_ID=778948
      - AUTH_OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET=some-client-secret
      - AUTH_OIDC_DISCOVERY_URI=http://dqt:8000/openid/.well-known/openid-configuration/
      - AUTH_OIDC_BASE_URL=http://datahub:9002/
    hostname: datahub
    image: linkedin/datahub-frontend-react:${DATAHUB_VERSION:-head}
    ports:
      - 9002:9002
  
  datahub-gms:
    container_name: datahub-gms
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - DATASET_ENABLE_SCSI=false
      - EBEAN_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=datahub
      - EBEAN_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=datahub
      - EBEAN_DATASOURCE_HOST=mysql:3306
      - EBEAN_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/datahub?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
      - EBEAN_DATASOURCE_DRIVER=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
      - KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER=broker:29092
      - KAFKA_SCHEMAREGISTRY_URL=http://schema-registry:8081
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=elasticsearch
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=9200
      - GRAPH_SERVICE_IMPL=elasticsearch
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g
      - ENTITY_REGISTRY_CONFIG_PATH=/datahub/datahub-gms/resources/entity-registry.yml
      - MAE_CONSUMER_ENABLED=true
      - MCE_CONSUMER_ENABLED=true
    hostname: datahub-gms
    image: linkedin/datahub-gms:${DATAHUB_VERSION:-head}
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ${HOME}/.datahub/plugins:/etc/datahub/plugins
  
  elasticsearch:
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx256m -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true
    healthcheck:
      retries: 4
      start_period: 2m
      test:
        - CMD-SHELL
        - curl -sS --fail 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?wait_for_status=yellow&timeout=0s' || exit 1
    hostname: elasticsearch
    image: elasticsearch:7.9.3
    mem_limit: 1g
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  
  elasticsearch-setup:
    container_name: elasticsearch-setup
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOST=elasticsearch
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PORT=9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PROTOCOL=http
    hostname: elasticsearch-setup
    image: linkedin/datahub-elasticsearch-setup:${DATAHUB_VERSION:-head}
  
  kafka-setup:
    container_name: kafka-setup
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    environment:
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER=broker:29092
    hostname: kafka-setup
    image: linkedin/datahub-kafka-setup:${DATAHUB_VERSION:-head}
  
  mysql:
    command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_bin
    container_name: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=datahub
      - MYSQL_USER=datahub
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=datahub
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=datahub
    hostname: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ../mysql/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
  
  mysql-setup:
    container_name: mysql-setup
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=mysql
      - MYSQL_PORT=3306
      - MYSQL_USERNAME=datahub
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=datahub
      - DATAHUB_DB_NAME=datahub
    hostname: mysql-setup
    image: acryldata/datahub-mysql-setup:head
  
  schema-registry:
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - broker
    environment:
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schemaregistry
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL=zookeeper:2181
    hostname: schema-registry
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.4.0
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
  
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
      - ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME=2000
    hostname: zookeeper
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.4.0
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    volumes:
      - zkdata:/var/opt/zookeeper

volumes:
  dqt_local_postgres_data: {}
  dqt_local_postgres_data_backups: {}
  esdata: null
  mysqldata: null
  zkdata: null
```

In the above, container `datahub-frontend-react` is supposed to integrate into container `dqt` for the OIDC authentication.

The docker log doesn't show any exceptions, and the http code is 200:

```
dqt                       | [28/Feb/2022 10:43:43] "GET /openid/.well-known/openid-configuration/ HTTP/1.1" 200 682
dqt                       | [28/Feb/2022 10:43:44] "GET /openid/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdatahub%3A9002%2F%2Fcallback%2Foidc&state=9Fj1Bog-ZN8fhN2kufWng2fRGaqCYnkMz6n3yKxPowo&client_id=778948&scope=openid+profile+email HTTP/1.1" 200 126
```

Here's the redirect_uri configuration in django admin:
[image]

I'm suspecting it could be related to the fact that they are different containers with different hostnames (I don't know what to do about that).

What could be the root cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your log shows that the app is redirecting with this login URL, with two `%2F` characters, so the URL used by the app is different to that configured:

```
http://datahub:9002//callback/oidc
```

**INTERNAL AND EXTERNAL URLs**

Not sure if it will work once you resolve that though, since the callback URL looks like a Docker Compose internal URL, that the browser will be unable to reach. Aim to return a URL such as this instead:

```
http://localhost:9002/callback/oidc
```

One option that can be useful to make URLs more understandable during development, and to plan the real deployment, is to add custom host names to your computer's hosts file. You can then login via URLs such as http://www.myapp.com, which I find clearer.

See these resources for something to compare against, which describe a setup with both internal and external URLs.

- [Custom Hosts](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-handler-spa-example/#configure-urls)
- [Docker Compose Example](https://github.com/curityio/spa-deployments/blob/main/standard/docker-compose.yml#L28)